# Websocket blocks without timing out on client plug pull/power loss

Tags: java, sockets, websocket, spring-websocket

I have an odd issue with my Tomcat + Spring websocket application. When a user disconnects without sending a "closing" signal, due to power loss or a plug pull, the thread will block ***about 10 seconds later***.

The thread blocks on this function :

```
org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession.sendMessage(WebSocketMessage<?> wsm) throws IOException;
```

I have tried putting a line in my AppConfig to try and set a timeout of 3 seconds but it does not seem to work properly as the ***block seems to go on for upwards of 15 minutes before throwing an exception***.

```
@Bean(name="servletServerContainerFactoryBean")
public int maxSessionIdleTimeout() {
  return 3000;
}
```

Here is the stack trace after an *eventual* SocketTimeoutException

```
Step: 2304
SendB -> test isOpen -> sendMes -> Done -> Finished Send.
SendB -> test2 isOpen -> sendMes -> User closed connection during packet sending: s01
Propogating exception up!
java.io.IOException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:315)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:250)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendPartialString(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointBasic.sendText(WsRemoteEndpointBasic.java:49)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketSession.sendTextMessage(StandardWebSocketSession.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.AbstractWebSocketSession.sendMessage(AbstractWebSocketSession.java:102)
    at org.infpls.noxio.game.module.game.session.NoxioSession.sendPacket(NoxioSession.java:40)
    at org.infpls.noxio.game.module.game.dao.lobby.GameLobby.step(GameLobby.java:117)
    at org.infpls.noxio.game.module.game.dao.lobby.GameLobby$GameLoop.run(GameLobby.java:274)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.doWrite(WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.writeMessagePart(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:309)
    ... 8 more
## CRITICAL ## Ejecting player: test2 :: Exception thrown on packet send...
java.io.IOException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:315)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:250)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendPartialString(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointBasic.sendText(WsRemoteEndpointBasic.java:49)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketSession.sendTextMessage(StandardWebSocketSession.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.AbstractWebSocketSession.sendMessage(AbstractWebSocketSession.java:102)
    at org.infpls.noxio.game.module.game.session.NoxioSession.sendPacket(NoxioSession.java:40)
    at org.infpls.noxio.game.module.game.dao.lobby.GameLobby.step(GameLobby.java:117)
    at org.infpls.noxio.game.module.game.dao.lobby.GameLobby$GameLoop.run(GameLobby.java:274)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.doWrite(WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.writeMessagePart(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:309)
    ... 8 more
Finished Send. Step Finished.
```

Having threads be blocked for 15 minutes at a time is a major problem. Any info on why this happens and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer finally. It's actually a system setting.

[Source](https://www.redhat.com/archives/redhat-install-list/2005-October/msg00105.html)

```
How many times to retry before deciding that something is wrong and
it is necessary to report this suspicion to network layer. Minimal RFC
value is 3, it is default, which corresponds to  3sec-8min depending on
RTO.
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_retries2
```